# In Linux, how can I determine the power consumption of my HDD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, power, power-consumption

Is there a way to determine how much power my HDD(s) are using? I'm running typical (oldish) desktop with an 848P chipset and Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (Wheezy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can get an answer to that via any OS. The power supply of most drives will be directly connected from the PSU to the HDD. There is nothing in between which can measure how much power is used.

That leaves three options:

1. Put something in between and somehow read it from that device. (Which means you will need a device which measure and which is somehow connected to the computer).
2. Or get a PSU with this build in (I never saw one since this would raise the price and consumers mostly want cheap stuff).
3. Get the information from the HDD itself.

As far as I know there is no drive which measure this, though you might make an estimate by extracting the total running time, time spun up and an average of activity using S.M.A.R.T.  One of the tools which can read those values on linux is [hdparm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hdparm/).

If you just want a rough figure: I do measure the power input to my desktop (before PSU losses) and adding an older 15K RPM SAS drive or 1TB SATA drives raised power by about 10W idle and 20 Watt (spin up).

That means that you can save a lot from your power bill (and heat and noise production) by not using many old drives.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do is to look at the device information label.[image]

As you can see in the above image the power required is 12V x 1.6A = 19.2W
This will be close to the power estimation that you might get from any software as this is the highest expected power requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The hard drive does not provide a real time power consumption interface for the OS to call. I think the only practical way to do this is to hack into the SATA cable interface.
Also, you can't simply estimate power consumption by voltage * amps. There will be different power consumption in different situations, like idle, standby or busy reading.
**You can get close numbers for specific scenarios from the official documentation**.
[image]